# BuildFire source code - When users click my flash banner I need them to direct to safari/google browser. At the moment stuck in the app

Tags: buildfire

I added the code in the source code button so I could display a flash banner that when clicked takes you automatically to the  landing page, the banner displays well,  the only problem when you click the banner it does not take you to safari or google it stays stuck in the app itself so once a user clicks the banner they get stuck on the landing page within the app and can't even return to the app, without resetting their phones. What I need mine to do, a user clicks on the banner and then it automatically takes them to safari/google. Not stuck in the app.

What is coding to be added and where?

Source code for my banner

<iframe scrolling='no' frameBorder='0' style='padding:0px; margin:0px; border:0px;border-style:none;border-style:none;' width='800' height='800' src="http://urlremoved" ></iframe>

I tried adding this but does not work, but not sure where to add it or even if that is what I need to add

buildfire.navigation.openWindow

Answer (score 0):

You can use BuildFire WYSIWYG actions when adding buttons. Many plugins has it already. you can take a look at `Text WYSIWYG` or `Folder` plugins.

[image]

Next step would be selecting the "Web Content" action

[image]

Then whenever the use click the button it will take them.

---

You can also apply to images

[image]